# List of badges that can be earned several times

Tags: discussion, badges

I was looking at the list of badges on Stack Overflow and saw that a lot of badges can be earned more than one time.

---

- Is there a **list of all the badges** somewhere that can be achieved more
  than once?
- Furthermore, if it is not written in the description that we can get
  the badge several times, does that **necessarily** mean that this badge
  is unique?

Answer (score 9):

On Übermeta, there is a [list of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions), including if they can be achieved more than once, or not.

As for the descriptions, it seems that they are accurate. Even a badge like [Tumbleweed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed) which would make sense as a multi-awardable badge, can only be awarded once per user. While doing some research, I found users with multiple [Altruist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/222/altruist?userid=409473) or [Citizen Patrol](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol?userid=2679536) badges, but that seems to be a [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281744/some-one-time-only-badges-have-been-awarded-multiple-times) in the system.

Comment: There's also a list in [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges), but it's not quite as good as the one on Meta.SE.