# Can the Pundit badge be earned multiple times?

Tags: support, badges

Can the Pundit badge be earned multiple times?

The description says:

> Pundit: Leave 10 comments with score of 5 or more.

So it doesn't tell if it can be awarded once or more.

Comment: [No](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/347191). its awarded only once

Comment: Related: [List of badges that can be earned several times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329914/7795130).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/363946):

> #### Pundit
>
> - silver; awarded once
> - Leave ten comments, each of which has a score of at least five
> - Leave 10 comments that each have a score of at least 5 (this was reduced from 10 to 5 on Nov 2, 2010)
> - Comments on deleted posts count towards the badge ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109629/255554)), deleted comments do not ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79555/255554))
> - Automatically generated comments (e.g. 'Possible duplicate of') count as long as they're not deleted
> - There will never be a gold version of this badge ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78049))